# Como hacer que un If arroje una sola respuesta si se cumple la condición y no las dos, python

Tags: python, string, condiciones

```
import random

nombre = input("introduzca su nombre: ")
print("Mi estimado ", nombre, "su porcentaje de amistad es: ", random.randint(0, 100), "%")
if 'marcio' == nombre:
    print("Su porcentaje de amistad es 0%")
```

*cuando escribo marcio (cuando se supone que debería arrojar 0%) pone:*

```
introduzca su nombre: marcio
Mi estimado  marcio su porcentaje de amistad es:  47 %
Su porcentaje de amistad es 0%

Process finished with exit code 0
```

*También me gustaria saber como le puedo hacer para que a la hora de que escriba marcio de cualquier manera (Marcio, MARCIO, mArciO, etc..) siga arrojando el valor de 0% muchas gracias.
(pd estoy aprendiendo python por mi propia cuenta xD perdón si es algo demasiado obvio pero he leido y no he encontrado algo que me de solución)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que un valor permanezca, tienes que guardarlo en una variable. La variable puede tener cualquier nombre, excepto las palabras reservadas.

Para comparar cualquier cadena con una referencia, en minúsculas por ejemplo, basta con aplicarle el método `.lower()` y así no importa si la escribe en mayusculas, minusculas o intercaladas.

```
import random

nombre = input("introduzca su nombre: ")
pr_amistad = random.randint(0, 100) # <-- Variable que almacena el %
if 'marcio' == nombre.lower():
    print("Su porcentaje de amistad es 0%")
else:
    print("Mi estimado ", nombre, "su porcentaje de amistad es: ", pr_amistad, "%")
```

Ahora bien, Python provee formas más sencillas de escribir cadenas, por ejemplo, reemplazando la línea respectiva por:

```
print(f"Mi estimado {nombre} su porcentaje de amistad es: {pr_amistad}%")
```

Comment: hola, muchas gracias por responder, ejecute tu codigo y a la hora de poner marcio me siguen saliendo los dos valores, cuando quiero que cuando sea Marcio ponga de un solo "su porcentaje de amistad es 0%"
introduzca su nombre: marcio
Mi estimado  marcio su porcentaje de amistad es:  35 %
Su porcentaje de amistad es: 0%

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Ok, no entendía bien @P4Kubz . Cuando es marcio es 0%, y otro nombre un porcentaje random. Listo, ya lo modifiqué.

Comment: omg muchas gracias te agradezco esto era lo que quería hacer jaja pero no encontraba como.